# I need help with a proof in a francis clarke's book

Tags: functional-analysis

In the book "Francis Clarke - Functional analysis, calculus of variations and optimal control" in the theorem 5.22 it says the following:

> let $f(x):X\to\mathbb{R}_{\infty}$ be lower semicontinuous. Suppose
>   that for some $x\in$dom$f$ and positive numbers $\delta$ and $r$ we
>   have:
>   $$\liminf_{w\to u, u\neq w} \frac{f(w)-f(u)}{||w-u||}\leq -\delta\quad\forall u\in B^{\circ}(x,r)$$
>   then $$\inf\{f(u):u\in B^{\circ}(x,r)\}\leq f(x)-\delta r$$

then it proceeds to proof by contradiction stating that there exists some $\eta\in(0,r/2)$ such that:
$$\inf\{f(u):u\in B(x,r-\eta)\}+\delta (r-2\eta)\geq f(x)$$
 I was able to prove that, but then the book says that we can use Ekland's theorem on $E:=B(x,r-\eta)$, to deduce that for any $\lambda\in (0,r/2)$ there exists $z\in B(x,\lambda)$ such that:
$$f(w)+\frac{\delta(r-2\eta)}{\lambda}||w-z||>f(z)\quad \forall w\in B(x,r-\eta),w\neq z$$ 
yet it does not mention that $X$ is complete (wich is required in the Ekland theorem) and I have tried to prove that $E=B(x,r-\eta)$ (as defined before) is complete, frist by contradiction taking a cauchy sequence and claiming it was not convergent, and directly by taking an arbitrary cauchy sequence and try to prove it converges to some value in $E$.

Can it be proved that $E$ is complete? I do understand the following steps of the proof, but I can't use this proof if $E$ is not complete.